# How to make a pointer iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, listiterator

For some reason I can't make a pointer iterator. Is it disabled? I tried to do it but it doesn't work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<class T>
void convertListToVector(std::list<T> *listItem) {
typename std::list<T>::iterator it;
for (it = *listItem->begin(); it != *listItem->end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> listExample;
    listExample.push_back("2");
    listExample.push_back("3");
    listExample.push_back("5");
    convertListToVector(&listExample);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >}' and 'std::basic_string<char>')|
error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >}' and 'std::basic_string<char>')|
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're passing `listItem` in as a pointer instead of as a reference?

Comment: Because i love pointers @tadman . (Odd Character..)

Comment: What you love and what's a good idea are clearly at *odds* here. Pointers have a number of disadvantages, both from a performance and code correctness perspective. Use the best tool for the job, not the one that you're the most used to. You simply presume that `listItem` is a valid pointer, that it's not `NULL`, which could be a big mistake. A reference is generally always valid, so this test is done by the compiler, no code required.

Comment: Plus, the list container already has a pointer, so pointer within a pointer to point the pointer??? xD

Comment: `*listItem->begin()` should be `listItem->begin()` or `(*listItem).begin()`. Same for `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use them as references and make it easy for your self...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<class T>
void convertListToVector(std::list<T> &listItem) {
typename std::list<T>::iterator it;
for (it = listItem.begin(); it != listItem.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> listExample;
    listExample.push_back("2");
    listExample.push_back("3");
    listExample.push_back("5");
    convertListToVector(listExample);

    return 0;
}
```

### Rule Of Thumb

Use references the whole time. Only pointers when you **have** to. You may ask why?

1. Pointers tend to confuse programmers. Even experienced ones.
2. Pointers can change what they are 'pointing' to. Which can be terrible
   in some occasions.
3. Pointers can be null.. For example:

In **C++11**:

```
   int *p1 = nullptr;
```

Other C++:

```
   int *p1 = NULL;
   int *p2 = 0;
```

4. References have to reference an object. Meaning you cant just put a number 
   on a 'reference' of int

### Best Practices

1: Note that you can't change what references are referencing so just add the keyword `const` before your references, so they dont change what they are pointing to. It's best practice and also makes sure you don't make a silly mistake as changing what your references are referencing.

```
  const int x = 0;
  const int &ref = x
```

Comment: That's the text-book example, nothing fancy, which is really the way to do it.

Comment: @Joel xD . tadman, yes thats the normal way to do it! Ima add in something to!

Comment: @Dsafds To get really in line with C++ best practices here, could add `const` to the reference to make sure someone doesn't get *ideas* about changing data and also to hint to the compiler that it's okay to optimize accordingly.

Comment: Wow @tadman i didnt know that for my-self! That is a very good idea/practice! Added it into anwser, thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `operator*` at all, `listItem->begin()` will return the iterator.

```
for (it = listItem->begin(); it != listItem->end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it <<std::endl;
}
```

---

<sup>I'm trying to answer you question straightforward, just as other answerer said, you don't need to pass `listItem` by pointer here, passing by reference should be sufficient.</sup>